# Why does my Node.js stream return something when invoking its read function?

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm having trouble understanding, why the following works, that is, why the invocations of the `read()` function actually return the objects stored in the readable stream.

```
const { Readable } = require('stream')
var r = new Readable({objectMode: true, read: () => {}}) // dummy read
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
r.push(...a)
```

Now, when I invoke `r.read()` I get the numbers I pushed into my readable stream `r`

```
r.read() // -> 1
r.read() // -> 2
// etc
```

But I provided a "dummy" `read` function (`read: () => {}`) above when creating my readable stream. So, why do I get values back, when calling `read`?

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple. You're calling the `push` method which should be called by your `read` implementation.

The purpose of `push` is to say: here's what I've read from the source, but it doesn't have to be called from within the internal methods.

In other words in the process:

- wait for _read to be called
- _read something from source
- push the read chunks to stream
- return the chunks from read

You simply skipped the two first steps and pushed the data from outside.

Comment: So, am I correct in assuming that the provided `read() => {}` function is _not_ the one called when invoking `r.read()`. Or in other words `read() => {}` is not `read([size])`?

Comment: You are and you're not. It's called alright, but not directly. There's quite a lot machinery in the stream class that calls your _read implementation. Put a `console.log` in your read function and see for yourself - I suspect _read will get called before your read call.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed that helped. The two methods are interlinked in the call stack, but are not identical. That clears my earlier confusion, indeed. I cannot help but wonder, whether the _identical_ naming `read` of the two functions one that reads data _into_ the stream and the other that reads data _from_ the stream has been a wise choice.

Comment: Well - that's why I refer to the internal `_read` with the underscore - if you were to implement a class derived from `Readable` then you can simply implement that underscore method. Passing the `read` function is simply another way of passing this.